# Designing a mixed signal circuit for the first time

Tags: power-supply, low-power

I am designing my first mixed signal circuit. I will then have a analog and digital ground plane and my question is:

To be able to have separate grounds (analog and digital) on a battery powered device, one would have to have two batteries? One that powers the analog part and one that powers the digital part? Or is it normal to use just one battery and connect the ground planes at the battery GND terminal? And if the analog and digital part needs 3.3V and 5V respectively one would just regulate a common power source of, e.g. 6V and only use the 3.3V for analog components and the 5V for digital components?

Comment: http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/anniversary/12.html might be worth a read

Comment: @Bitrex: Good link! What I learned is that all components that got both AGND and DGND (ADC, DACs etc.) should be connected and have a bypass capacitor to the analog ground plane. If only one component in the design has both AGND and DGND pins the analog and digital planes can be connected at the component. What is unclear to me and that I need confirmation on is that if I have more than one component with both AGND and DGND pins, should the planes be interconnected at the battery's ground? And when reading about using two power sources how do I know if I have a "quiet" digital ground or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you only need 1 battery.  The idea behind separate ground planes is that you want to minimize the return currents from the digital circuitry that flow through the analog ground plane.  In the case of ADCs and DACs, connect all of the ground pins to the analog ground.  Yes, even if they are 'digital ground' pins.  Then split the analog ground plane and digital ground plane, and connect them to each other at the power supply.  There are a number of RAQs from Analog Devices that address this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have different ground filling for analog and digital grounds. Connect the two grounds with a ferrite bead. The main reason for the noise in the analog circuits in the mixed signal design is that the high frequency switching noise currents flowing through the long ground path will lift the ground due the to the trace inductance. Please see the diagram attached here[image]